# Can salami mold make dry-aged salami un-kosher?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat

I am making beef salami, using kosher meat, and I would like to know if the mold that is introduced to form on the outside can make it non-kosher.

**Background info**

---

Dry aged meats take advantage of a 'good mold', which is related to penicillin, to protect against mad molds which can ruin the meat.  In order to dry age salami, you must utilize this mold. (For example, [here](https://www.sausagemaker.com/bactoferm-mold-600-p/11-1312.htm) is the product I used.) The mold grows on the outside of the casing, and the entire casing is removed before eating.

***YOU DO NOT EAT THE MOLD***

My question:
**Assuming that everything else is kosher, can the addition of the mold make it unkosher?**

My setup:
[image: Salamis, coated with mold on the outside of their casings, hanging vertically]

Comment: Why would you think it would not be kosher?

Comment: In general, mold is kosher. It is a natural substance. What of course, does need some research is that if mold grows on a non-kosher food, I would think it's non-kosher.  If the salami is kosher, the mold should be kosher too. For my curiosity, why would you want to eat this?

Comment: Its an Italian dry aged salami, made with kosher beef from a kosher butcher.  https://forum.sausagemaking.org/viewtopic.php?t=10590

Comment: Thanks. I read this on Wikipedia. Interesting info. It doesn't look great, but I gather it adds flavor to the salami. I can't see why this mold would be non-kosher. Mold is sometimes added to cheese, also. I think blue cheese uses the same type of mold as what you're using.

Comment: What reason do have to assume that mold isn't kosher or would make something unkosher?